# GLSL double precision complex number power function

Tags: glsl

I currently have the following GLSL functions defined for raising a complex number to a power.

```
dvec2 p2 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(t,t) ));}
dvec2 p3 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(t,t),t) ));}
dvec2 p4 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(cmul(t,t),t),t) ));}
dvec2 p5 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(t,t),t),t),t) ));}
dvec2 p6 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(t,t),t),t),t),t) ));}
dvec2 p7 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(t,t),t),t),t),t),t) ));}
dvec2 p8 (dvec2 t) {return (dvec2 (cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(cmul(t,t),t),t),t),t),t),t) ));}
```

I can use these in complex number formula like

```
dvec2 func (dvec2 z) { return (dvec2( cadd(csub(p4(z),cmul(c5,p2(z))),c4) ));
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to get rid of those p2,p3,p4,etc functions and write a more generalized power function.  So I tried the following

```
dvec2 cpow (dvec2 c, int p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    c=cmul(c,c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

which I then call like

```
dvec2 func   (dvec2 z) { return (dvec2( cadd(csub(cpow(z,4),cmul(c5,cpow(z,2))),c4) )); }
```

But it gives different results.  I can find a lot of complex power routines online but they all use log and trig calls which are not double precision which I need for this GLSL code.

Can any GLSL gurus spot why that simple cpow loop would not work?

Comment: You don't need to be a "GLSL guru" to spot an off-by-one error. I don't remember complex arithmetic that well, but as just a sanity check, (X,0) to the power 0 ought to be (1, 0), right? And (X, 0) to the power 1 ought to be (X, 0), right?

Comment: The code isn't raising the complex number to the loop variable though?  It is just repeatedly multiplying by itself in the loop.

Comment: Are you saying that `cpow(something, 1)` does not mean "raise `something` to the power 1?" If not, what is it *supposed* to do, and why do you call it `cpow`? Indeed, you want to replace `p2(z)` with `cpow(z, 2)`, so *you* seem to think that `cpow` is supposed to raise numbers to the power you give it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, cpow(z,4) is supposed to raise z to the power of 4 by repeatedly multiplying z by itself in a loop.

Comment: If you want to raise X to the power 4, how many `*`s would you have to write in the code? Now compare that to how many times your loop would do it.

Comment: OK, but changing p in the loop to p-1 still does not replicate the other function results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your conversion formula is wrong ... because you multiply by the subresult meaning you got squaring instead of multiplying ... You have to change your function to:

```
dvec2 cpow (dvec2 c, int p) 
    {
    dvec2 a=(1.0,0.0); // assuming a.x is real part
    for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) a=cmul(a,c);
    return a;
    }
```

if you want something faster you can use [power by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) or even port to polar representation do power there and convert back to cartesian form of complex number. For more info see:

- [How to express tetration function, for complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735614/2521214)

Look for the `vec2 cpow(vec2 a,vec2 b)    // a^b` in the GLSL code for tetration fractal.