# WEBGL: How to Color a Fractal Design within the Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am looking to color a fractal within my fragment shader in an WebGL project.

Within my fragment shader, I have a vec3 called Color that contains the RGB values from 0.0-1.0.

To make a fractal design similar to

[image]

but in black and white,

what would I need to set the Color vector to? This color is then multiplied by the Weighted Lighting for the gl_FragColor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find a way to color the Mandelbrot-set the way i'm aiming for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195735/cant-find-a-way-to-color-the-mandelbrot-set-the-way-im-aiming-for)

Comment: heh I fully missed the B&W (I think you mean grayscale instead) that is easy if your color is from 0 to 1 let call it `c` then the grayscale output color would be `vec4(c,c,c,1.0);` ... so `r=g=b=c`

Answer (score -1):

Mandelbrot shaders typically have loop that evaluates an escape condition. To make a monochrome image, simply set `Color` to `vec3(0)` if the number of iterations to escape is less than some threshold `T`, and set it to `vec3(1)` otherwise. For an example, see [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3d3SDl) shader toy.