# GLSL Pow Function for doubles

Tags: double, glsl, shader

Is there a way to calculate powers of doubles in GLSL?

The pow function gives me this error when trying to use doubles:

`unable to find compatible overloaded function "pow(float64_t, float)"`

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

- [ARB_gpu_shader_fp64](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_fp64.txt)

the extension is missing any `goniometric,pow,exp,log` functions.

So you can not use 64bit pow nor encode it using [log,exp approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072451/2521214). You still might be able to implement [Power by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) or your own [log,exp functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) for this. I think for that exact reason they added these:

```
genDType frexp(genDType x, out genIType exp);
genDType ldexp(genDType x, in genIType exp);
```

However I never used them I just found them while searching the doc for `log/exp/pow` functions. Also implementing `pow` in GLSL will be a hard work due to lack of breakpoints, stepping/tracing ... This might help a lot:

- [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214)

But still I suggest to implement this on CPU side first and once working then port to GLSL.

Comment: The reason I need doubles is because im writing a shader to zoom into the mandelbrot set. I need pow to calculate the distance to each point. Im not sure if it even has to be double precision, but it looks weird when zoomed in too far. Im just trying to replace all floats with double.

Comment: @Kport you do not need `pow` for that as Mandelbrot does not have any pow in its equation And the `sqr(x)` can be simply done by `x*x` see [Can't find a way to color the Mandelbrot-set the way i'm aiming for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197067/2521214) and [how do I get infinitely small numbers (for fractals)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018319/2521214)

Answer (score -1):

`pow` requires both arguments to be the same. You can take a look at the documentation [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml). You could probably cast the variable before using `pow`:

```c
pow(float(your_variable), the_power);
```

or

```c
pow(your_variable, float64_t(the_power));
```

As I have never worked with float64_t before, I am not sure this will work. I am pretty sure the first one will, though.

Comment: The first one works, but i lose the accuracy i need. The second one gives the same error.

Comment: its a shame but there is no 64bit `pow` function in GLSL (at least that I know of)