# Use two float point variables as a single float

Tags: math, floating-point, glsl, precision

I was wondering if there was a nice way to combine two float point variables and use it like 1 float point variable with extra precision.

The purpose is for use in a GLSL shader where I would like to have more precision in the calculations. (Fractal Zoom). The version of the shader language I used had access to float point numbers but no integers.

The operations I need on the higher precision float point number are just additional / subtraction & multiplication.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks! didn't see the duplicate.

Comment: see [how do I get infinitely small numbers (for fractals)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018319/2521214)